# NSScrollView - How to change the margins where autoscrolling occurs when dragging

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

I have an NSScrollView and items inside which I can re-arrange by drag & drop. And it auto-scrolls when I drag the items to the bottom & drop of the NSScrollView, but it only operates in a very small area. If my drag is not within about 4-6 pixels of the edge, auto-scroll does not happen. How do I increase this area?

Comment: plz add some code for such question ! you are more likely to get better suggestion for codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSTrackingArea` which you can set in the NSScrollView (there are some example projects by Apple) or you could overwrite the `- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent` from NSResponder. If you use `mouseDragged`you probably need to keep attention to calculate with the right coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

I think the accepted answer here may be what you are looking for:

[NSTableView in NSScrollView doesn't autoscroll when dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609711/nstableview-in-nsscrollview-doesnt-autoscroll-when-dragging)