# NSTableView in NSScrollView doesn't autoscroll when dragging

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, nsscrollview

I'm currently implementing drag and drop rearranging in a table view in my OS X app. While normal scrolling works fine, autoscroll while dragging it totally broken.

If I grab a cell and start dragging, autoscroll just tells the table to scroll to the top. If I manually scroll using the trackpad during dragging the table continually pops to the top. If I drag one of the top cells, the table will not autoscroll down when dragging near the bottom.

I subclassed NSScrollView and overrode the `scrollClipView` method. I see that it's being called by some internal autoscroll method with the coordinates of (0, 0).

[image]

Since I can't see what that internal method is doing, and Goggle and SO are turning up nothing, I'm a bit stuck.

Has anyone run into this issue before? From past experiences, I have the feeling it's something AutoLayout related, but I have no idea what. Or maybe it's something completely unrelated.

Any ideas on how to further troubleshoot?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: What code are you interested in seeing? Given the nature of this application, I cannot expose large portions of the code base. Is there anything in particular?

Comment: I'm interested in "I subclassed NSScrollView and overrode the scrollClipView method."

Comment: I did that only for debugging to check to see where it was being called from. Otherwise, I do not override that method.

Comment: override func scrollClipView(aClipView: NSClipView, toPoint aPoint: NSPoint) {
        if aPoint.x == 0 && aPoint.y == 0 {
            Swift.print("break")
        }
        
        super.scrollClipView(aClipView, toPoint: aPoint)
    } I added a breakpoint on the print line. Otherwise it just calls super.

Comment: The scroll view is bone stock with the exception of the following being set: wantsLayer = true, contentView.wantsLayer = true, drawsBackground = false

Comment: When in doubt, blame auto layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. In my case, the problem was that I set the height of the `NSTableCellView` to 10,000 in Interface Builder so that the horizontal separators wouldn’t be displayed for empty rows below the actual rows.

However, the actual height of my `NSTableCellViews` loaded at run time was 43px.

So as soon as I started dragging a cell to re-order it, the `NSScrollView` was trying to scroll 10,000 pixels at a time instead of 43 at a time.

This seems like a bug, because my `NSOutlineView` subclass does implement the following method to dynamically set the height of each row.

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, heightOfRowByItem item: Any) -> CGFloat
```

Apparently that method is ignored by the autoscroll mechanism during drag and drop operations, and only the value set in Interface Builder is used.

So I just changed the height of the dummy `NSTableCellView` to 43px in Interface Builder, and I’ll just live with the horizontal separators being displayed for empty rows.